# A Mono compatible OData v4 client

Tags: .net, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin, odata

For a (iOS/Android) Xamarin project, I need to communicate with an OData v4 API. I first had a look at the [Simple OData Client](https://components.xamarin.com/view/simple.odata.client), but that library does not yet support OData v4.

I'm now trying to use the OData Client Code Generator (which uses [Microsoft's OData Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OData.Client/6.6.0)):

```
var commonContainer = new Default.Container(new Uri(serviceUri)); 
commonContainer.BuildingRequest += (sender, args) => 
    args.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + _token);
var companies = await commonContainer.Company.ExecuteAsync();
```

This however throws the following exception:

> Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQueryException: An error occurred while processing this request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred while processing this request. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.\n  at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.AsyncEndRead (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task, System.Object asyncState) [0x00000] in :0 \n  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\n  at Microsoft.OData.Client.BaseAsyncResult.EndExecute[QueryResult] (System.Object source, System.String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in :0 \n  at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.EndExecuteQuery[Company] (System.Object source, System.String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in :0 \n  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\n  at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.EndExecuteQuery[Company] (System.Object source, System.String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in :0 \n  at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.EndExecute[Company] (System.Object source, Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext context, System.String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in :0 \n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in :0 \n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyApp.Api.MyDomainModel.Company]].GetResult () [0x00000] in :0 \n  at MyApp.MyApi+d__c.MoveNext () [0x000d8] in c:\Workspace\MyApp\trunk\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp\MyApi.cs:54 \n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in :0 \n  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyApp.Api.MyDomainModel.Company]].GetResult () [0x00000] in :0 \n  at MyApp.ContentPages.ConsultDashboardPage+d__11.MoveNext () [0x00040] in c:\Workspace\MyApp\trunk\MyApp\MyApp\MyApp\ContentPages\ConsultDashboardPage.cs:15

Could this mean that `Microsoft.OData` isn't (fully) compatible with Mono?

Is there maybe a different OData v4 client I can use or would I have to use `HttpClient` to create my own OData requests?

Comment: You can try OData Client for .NET, http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OData.Client/

Comment: Thanks, but that's the client that I'm already using. See the exception: `Cannot cast from source type to destination type. at Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.AsyncEndRead`

Comment: Then maybe you can with the links I posted in the answers. Also, there will be a Java OData V4 client, but not completed yet. You can take a look at https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=olingo-odata4.git;a=summary if you are insterested.

Comment: I've used version 1 of http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9b786c0e-79d1-4a50-89a5-125e57475937 with ODataLib 6.4 (or whatever the version that's compatible with 1 was at the time) and it worked just fine.

Comment: I'm using the OData v4 Client Code Generator version 2.0.0 with the latest Mono, Xamarin Studio and Gtk# and have written similar application and it also works fine. Maybe you could add more context for your project, the complete call stack, or a broader extent of the application code?

Comment: I'm using Xamarin Forms with the Xamarin Visual Studio plugin, but I also get the same exception using Xamarin Studio on an iOS device with Xamarin Studio. I edited my question with more info on the exception.

Answer (score 0):

There are various kinds of libraries you can choose http://www.odata.org/libraries/ . Maybe you can try the new C++ client https://github.com/OData/odatacpp which should have a better capability with Mono.